# Wave equation derivation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, soft-question, physics

What is the purpose of taking the curl of both sides of Maxwell's third equation? I'm fully able to follow this wave equation derivation, but I don't understand the initial premise of taking the curl of the curl.

(Here is the derivation in question)

https://youtu.be/u1a7DwkH7Ac

What does the curl of the curl physically represent, and why should one proceed this way?

Comment: I would suggest trying to do the curl of the curl of a few examples to see how it relates to the original function.

Comment: Do you mean the curl of the curl of an arbitrary vector field? What "original" function are you referring to?

Comment: Take a few vector fields and see what happens when you take the curl and then the curl of the curl. You can grow intuition by doing examples.

Comment: You just get the gradient of the divergence minus the laplacian